# Getting Current time in CAML QUERY

Tags: caml

I want to retrive 8 rows from list which is greater than current time (not date) using caml query. Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<Today />` tag to get current date , additionally if you add `IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'`, it will get you current time.

Try this:

```
<Where>
      <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name='YourColumnName' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
     </Gt>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a CAML query which includes time while doing comparisons. Check if this helps.

```
<Where>
  <And>
     <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2011-02-09T12:00:00Z</Value>
     </Gt>
     <Lt>
        <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2011-02-10T10:00:00Z</Value>
     </Lt>
  </And>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unnie Your query checks date as well as.But i need to compare only timings. Is that possible. I dont want to check date.